# Does deploying into one paired region automatically mean it's also deployed into the other?

Tags: azure

Azure has "South Central US" paired with "North Central US", they're a paired region.

If I deploy my web app or Function App into "South Central US" does that mean that it'll automatically get deployed into "North Central US" too and I can direct traffic to North Central as well?

Or is this not what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, An Azure Region Pair is a relationship between 2 Azure Regions within the same geographic region for disaster recovery purposes.

The real reason for having pair regions is that If one of the regions were to experience a disaster or failure, then the services in that region will automatically failover to that regions secondary region in the pair.

This is applicable to some of the services in Azure automatically for ex. Storage , Cosmosdb etc.

For Azure Functions,AppService you need to manually create the replication

Comment: Thanks, that's the missing piece of the puzzle. Is there a list somewhere of what services are automatically replicated and which are not and need manual intervention?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer. Region pairs are a feature of Azure. Its upto you whether to make use of that architecture or not when deploying your web application. Your costs will double compared to deploying to a single region and you will also require a front door service to correctly route web traffic to your backends. See here for the architecture & explanation from Microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/app-service-web-app/multi-region